# Saving network drive photo using webClient

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, base64, webclient

Hey all I have the following VB.net code that I need converted to C#:

```
 Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
 Dim imgLink As String = "\\the\path\photos\" + userID + ".jpg"
 Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(imgLink)))

 Dim mImage As String = ImageToBase64(tImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

That works just fine in VB but when I try to convert it to C#:

```
WebClient tClient = new WebClient();
string mImage = @"\\the\path\photos\" + userID + ".jpg";
Bitmap tImage = Bitmap.FromStream[new MemoryStream[tClient.DownloadData(mImage)]];

mImage = ImageToBase64(tImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It has an error on **tClient.DownloadData(imagePath)** saying:

> Error  7   Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'int'

What's the proper way to define this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues:

- You've mixed up the array operator bracket `[` with function call `(` bracket in Bitmap.FromStream and MemoryStream constructor
- You're downloading entire file at once, only to load it into a stream - that defeats the purpose of streaming
- Bitmap.FromStream actually comes from it's superclass, Image, and returns an Image (you have no guarantee the file will be an actual bitmap, not some other format - if you're sure of it, you'll have to cast it to Bitmap)

Try this:

```
WebClient tClient = new WebClient();
string mImage = @"\\the\path\photos\" + userID + ".jpg";
Bitmap tImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(tClient.OpenRead(mImage));

mImage = ImageToBase64(tImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

`WebClient.OpenRead` returns a stream you can pass straight to construct an image (without pulling all the data to a byte array)

Comment: Nice! That did the trick. Thanks for the help and also welcome to Stackoverflow! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use square bracket. But use bracket and declare a `new Bitmap`

```
WebClient tClient = new WebClient();
string mImage = @"\\the\path\photos\" + userID + ".jpg";
Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(mImage))));
```

And note that to [convert the image to base 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889764/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-a-base64-string) requires your `byte[]`, which you might as well take from the `tClient.DownloadData(mImage)`

```
mImage = Convert.ToBase64String(tClient.DownloadData(mImage));
```

Comment: @StealthRT also, check this out tho convert the image to base 64: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889764/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-a-base64-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64