# Convert bitmap returned from api to image in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, bitmap, base64

I have a bitmap for an image returned from api like ,what I get from api is a bitmap and not a base64 encoded string.

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8P8PAAAAAAAAAAAAAADA//8DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8/z8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAwDAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAcAAAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAMABABADAAAAAAAAAAAAAH4A/GMAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AfAPwYAAAAAAAAAAAAAxgAfZwAAAAAAAAAAAABgDPBxBgAAAAAAAAAAAACDAzHOAAAAAAAAAAAAADA4EOMMAAAAAAAAAAAAgAHGYIIBAAAAAAAAAAAAGGAMJhgAAAAAAAAAAACAAXzAggEAAAAAAAAAAAAYwAcsGAAAAAAAAAAAAMAAPIADAwAAAAAAAAAAAAzAAzgwAAAAAAAAAAAAwADmgAEDAAAAAAAAAAAADGAOGDAAAAAAAAAAAADAgIPBAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAMOBgMMAAAAAAAAAAAAMDgADcAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAwOcAMwAAAAAAAAAAAAwMAAHAADAAAAAAAAAAAADAzAATAAAAAAAAAAAADAgAA/AAMAAAAAAAAAAAAMCPADMAAAAAAAAAAAAIABA2GAAQAAAAAAAAAAABgwEAYYAAAAAAAAAAAAgAGGwYEBAAAAAAAAAAAAGGAYHBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+wAwwAAAAAAAAAAAAAwwA4wDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGOABuAAAAAAAAAAAAAGCAA+AGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYQAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAABgAcAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AAAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAIADAMABAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwP//AwAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/P8/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAADw/w8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

How can I convert it to base64 for converting to image using angular2.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889764/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-a-base64-string using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding Base64 Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: No I dont get a base64 image from api I want to convert this to base64 and then to image.

Comment: try [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function to convert it to base64

Comment: no it didnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bitmap Image. This seems like a base 64. If image is not drawing, try to get corrected base64 string from backend

Comment: No we are getting bitmap only from backend.

Comment: Ok. This may be what you got form the backend, But this is no BitMap. Bitmap is a byte array