# "Parameter is not valid" when creating a bitmap

Tags: c#, arrays, base64, restsharp

I am creating an [EmguCv Image object](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm) then retrieving it bytes and trying to create a Bitmap. This is my code

```
Image<Bgr, byte> myImg = new Image<Bgr, byte>("C:filePathToPng");
byte[] mybytes = myImg.Bytes; //This does NOT work
// byte[] m1bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:filePathToPng.png");    This does work
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(mybytes))
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream)) //PARAMETER IS NOT VALID HERE
{
....
```

However I am getting an error that is in the description.

**Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great**

Comment: Maybe the error happens when converting the Bitmap to the base64 string: See [How to convert Bitmap to a Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889764/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-a-base64-string)

Comment: This looks promising. One moment

Comment: All three suggestions did not work :(

Comment: Have you tried step debugging  in vs to see the exact line of code in which the code is failing?

Comment: Yes I have it is failing on the instantiation of the Bitmap

Comment: The Bitmap(Stream) constructor requires the stream to provide a valid image that is stored in one of the formats supported by the codecs.  Like a PNG, JPEG, BMP file, etc.  So definitely *not* the raw bytes in an emgu Image.  Lots and lots of existing posts on how to convert an Image to a Bitmap.

Comment: See my edits above. I know that it can be done but the File.ReadAllBytes is not an option in my situation. Need to pull bytes from an Emgu Image object appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a bitmap from an EmguImage did not work. Elected to save the image to disk, read all the bytes and then create a bitmap